# ValueError problema en Python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#datos
ep=0.8
D=0.001
Re=0.4
Ta=300
h=100
Too=300
I=5.2
c=390
rho=8960
sig=5.67*(10**(-8))
pi=3.14159265359
A=pi*(D**2)/4

#Condiciones iniciales
t=0
Tinc=300
u=Tinc

#Campo de direcciones 
def f(u,t):
    return ((Re*I**2)/(rho*c*A))-((pi*D*h*(u-Too))/(rho*c*A))- ((pi*D*ep*sig*((u**4)-(Ta**4)))/(rho*c*A))

#Solution
tsol=[t]
Tsol=[u]
dt=0.001
tfin=5

while t<tfin:
    k1=f(u,t)
    k2=f(u+dt+k1/2,t+dt/2)
    k3=f(u+dt*k2/2,t*dt/2)
    k4=f(u+dt*k3,t+dt)
    u=u+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*dt/6
    t=t+dt
    Tsol.append(u)
    Tsol.append(t)

plt.plot(tsol,Tsol)
plt.show()
```

Cuando le doy correr me sale el siguiente error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (10001,)
```

La ecuación es de transferencia de calor para un alambre delgado, y está basada en el primer ejemplo del [siguiente video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1DAmS_rmYQ&t=469s&ab_channel=CursosAbiertosUniversidad)

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

El error:

`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (10001,)`

Indica que una función que necesita que le pases elementos de la misma dimensión, le estás pasando elementos de distintas dimensiones. En concreto tu le debes pasar dos variables que sean **un vector de tamaño 10001**.

Este error como te indica la traza **completa** de error, se produce cuando intentas graficar, es decir aquí:

```
plt.plot(tsol,Tsol)
```

La función `plt.plot()` crea un gráfico de lineas, dicho gráfico necesita para cada punto una cordenada *X* y otra cordenada *Y*. El error que te está dando, dice que tienes **un solo dato** para la *X* y 10001 datos para la *Y*.

### Solución

El error viene de tu bucle `while`, en concreto tienes puesto dos veces `Tsol`. Cuando para este tipo de cálculo debes poner `tsol` y `Tsol`.

Este es un error muy frecuente en programación, sobre todo al incio, **trata de poner a las variables nombres que sean diferenciables y que te indiquen lo que es la variable, y la diferencien perfectamente de otras variables.** Si pones nombres que solo cambian las mayusculas como `Tsol` y `tsol` que son variables distintas (por la mayuscula). Es muy fácil confundir ambas variables, liarse y cometer errores. Aquí te dejo el bule `while` corregido:

```
while t<tfin:
    k1=f(u,t)
    k2=f(u+dt+k1/2,t+dt/2)
    k3=f(u+dt*k2/2,t*dt/2)
    k4=f(u+dt*k3,t+dt)
    u=u+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)*dt/6
    t=t+dt
    Tsol.append(u)
    tsol.append(t)
```